# MYSQL date range query strange behaviour

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

i'm working on codeigniter and mysql db. I have run in to a issue where i need to show recent data as per date.

i have table name tbl_tournament where i'm going to fetch tournament data whose `tournament_end_date >= $todays_date`

My Query

```
$today = date("d/m/Y");

        $this->db->select('*');

        $this->db->from('tbl_tournament');

        $this->db->where('is_deleted', FALSE);

        $this->db->where('tournament_end_date_time >=', $today);

        $this->db->order_by('tournament_start_date_time');

        $query = $this->db->get();

        return $query->result_array();
```

the output of this query is empty array
`array();`

When i manually change `tournament_end_date_time =  01/04/2018` in database and query `$this->db->where('tournament_end_date_time >=', '01/04/2017');` i get results. But when i change date in query as `$this->db->where('tournament_end_date_time >=', '31/12/2017');` i get empty array.

In Mysql database i have used varchar as the data type `tournament_end_date_time`

Thank in Advance.

Comment: Why are you using a varchar to store a formatted date string rather than a MySQL native date or datetime datatype? Use the correct datatype, and all your comparisons will  work correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You store datetimes as strings (with `VARCHAR` type), hence they're compared as strings - character by character. For obvious reasons, '3' character is greater than '1'. That's why with filter set...

```
WHERE tournament_end_date_time >= '31/12/2017'
```

... you'll only get the results where corresponding values start from '31/12' - in other words, of December, 31 (of 2017 - or any year after it).

To solve the problem, you can use [**STR_TO_DATE()**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) MySQL function to convert the existing column value to an actual date. Note that the param will be treated as a date literal as it follows 'YYYY-MM-DD' format:

```
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(tournament_end_date_time, '%d/%m/%Y') >= '2017-12-31'
```

... or, in PHP syntax, following CodeIgniter conventions:

```
$this->db->where(array(
  "STR_TO_DATE(tournament_end_date_time, '%d/%m/%Y') >=" => date("Y-m-d")
));
```

A better choice is doing a single-time update operation on this column to convert all its values to `DATE` type at once.

Comment: Thanks alot i have now change the data type to date